# How to programatically send a pre-composed message in ios 6?

Tags: ios6, messaging

Hi. I am developing an anti-theft app, in that I am sending a message on SIM change alert to an associated number. It worked perfectly up to the iOS version 5.0, but it is not working in iOS 6.0, Any solution for this issue is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send a message pro-grammatically in ios without third-party api,
Note : if you include a third party api you cannot enter into ios app-store.